# Facebook “Like” Button to iphone native app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Can anybody tell me how to add facebook like button in the Iphone native application without using UIWebview.

Thanks in advance

Nandita

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Graph API: after a successful login, make a HTTP POST request to

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[object ID]/likes
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Can you provide me with some sample code how to use that.